# Error 404 from ReST POST request method

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I would like to create a web application that accepts a single POST method to update a db, using a ReSTful structure.

My problem is that when I post a JSON object to the URL (using fiddler) I receive an error 404.

The method I am trying to call is exposed using the attributes below:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="projectors", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped )]
[OperationContract]
void RecordBreakdown(string sn, int modelCode);
```

The web config file has a service that binds to the exposed method, below is an abstraction:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings/>
  <services>
      <service name="VIServiceToolServiceLibrary.ProjectorService"
               behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehaviour">
      <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="VIServiceToolServiceLibrary.IProjectorService"
               behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndPointbehaviour"  />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/projectorservice/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>

<behaviors>      
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>      
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTEndPointbehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>      
</behaviors>
```

If I run the web app in VS or by IIS I can see the svc file okay:

```
http://localhost:5970/Service.svc
http://localhost/vi/Service.svc
```

But when I post a request I receive an error 404 message

```
POST http://localhost/vi/projectors HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 27

{sn:"23434", modelCode:34 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your base address in config and your running localhost port looks different. Use correct base address and then try

Comment: Your base address is different to the fiddler request, and is the project running or is it hosted in Iis already?

Comment: I am testing in iis. I have changed the base address to: http://localhost/vi/ and the URI contract in the interface to UriTemplate="vi/projectors" - still says error 404 (i have published the new changes to iis)

Comment: The base address was wrong and I was missing the suffex .svc off the url. http://localhost/vi/projectors should have been http://localhost/vi/Service.svc/projectors. If either of you want the points you can post an answer, else I'll put the answer myself

Answer (score 1):

The error 404 was happening for two reasons.

1st: The base address was incorrect. I was using a naming convention from an earlier version which had been superceeded

2nd: The url in the POST method was incorrect. I should have included the name of the Service file in the url, like localhost/vi/Service.svc/projectors

I also found the folloiwng article helpful
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx to solve the problem